# Function returns before fetch request completes

Tags: javascript, fetch

It seems my code is returning the values before completing the fetch request. I keep getting alert for 'invalid' before the alert for 'success'. Can anyone suggest a way to fix my problem? My full source code can be found here: https://github.com/SophalLee/project_04_sophal_lee.git.

```
registrationForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(checkInputs()) {
        alert('ok')
        //if(registrationForm.submit();
    }
    else {
        alert('Invalid')
    }
});

/* Validate input from form */
function checkInputs() {

    const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
    const lastnameValue = lastname.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const confirmPasswordValue = confirmPassword.value.trim();

    let firstnameSuccess = false;
    let lastnameSuccess = false;
    let emailSuccess = false;
    let passwordSuccess = false;
    let confirmPasswordSuccess = false;

  ....

    if(emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, "Email cannot be blank");
        emailSuccess = false;
    }
    else if(!emailCheck(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(email, "Invalid email");
        emailSuccess = false;
    }
    else {    
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ "email": emailValue }),       
         };

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/emailcheck', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => { 
            if(data.match) {
                setErrorFor(email, "Email already exists");
                emailSuccess = false;
            }
            else {
                setSuccessFor(email);
                emailSuccess = true;
                alert('success');
            }

        });
    }

  ....

    return (firstnameSuccess && lastnameSuccess && emailSuccess && passwordSuccess && confirmPasswordSuccess)    
}
```

Comment: Promises are run asynchronously. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I'm not sure where to put the promise in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the asynchronous functions return `Promise` as well as the surrounding `async` functions.  So `checkInputs()` also returns `Promise`.  In order to obtain the result, you have to either set the callback with `then()` or receive the returned value with `await` keyword.

I used the callback approach in the event listener.  And the `await` approach for receiving the result of email check with `fetch()`.

Note that `checkInputs()` returns the `Promise` instance that resolves to the boolean value upon finishing the asynchronous task.  You cannot simply check the booleans by invoking `if(checkInputs())`.

```
registrationForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkInputs().then(flag => {
    if (flag) {
      alert('ok')
      //if(registrationForm.submit();
    } else {
      alert('Invalid')
    }
  });
});

/* Validate input from form */
async function checkInputs () {

  const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
  const lastnameValue = lastname.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
  const confirmPasswordValue = confirmPassword.value.trim();

  let firstnameSuccess = false;
  let lastnameSuccess = false;
  let emailSuccess = false;
  let passwordSuccess = false;
  let confirmPasswordSuccess = false;

  // ....

  if (emailValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(email, "Email cannot be blank");
    emailSuccess = false;
  } else if (!emailCheck(emailValue)) {
    setErrorFor(email, "Invalid email");
    emailSuccess = false;
  } else {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ "email": emailValue }),
    };

    emailSuccess = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/emailcheck', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let emailFlag = false;
        if (data.match) {
          setErrorFor(email, "Email already exists");
          emailFlag = false;
        } else {
          setSuccessFor(email);
          emailFlag = true;
          alert('success');
        }
        return emailFlag;
      });
  }

  // ....

  return (firstnameSuccess && lastnameSuccess && emailSuccess && passwordSuccess && confirmPasswordSuccess)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Async Await for wait fetch request

```
registrationForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (checkInputs()) {
    alert('ok')
    //if(registrationForm.submit();
  }
  else {
    alert('Invalid')
  }
});

/* Validate input from form */
async function checkInputs() {

  const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
  const lastnameValue = lastname.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
  const confirmPasswordValue = confirmPassword.value.trim();

  let firstnameSuccess = false;
  let lastnameSuccess = false;
  let emailSuccess = false;
  let passwordSuccess = false;
  let confirmPasswordSuccess = false;


  if (emailValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(email, "Email cannot be blank");
    emailSuccess = false;
  }
  else if (!emailCheck(emailValue)) {
    setErrorFor(email, "Invalid email");
    emailSuccess = false;
  }
  else {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ "email": emailValue }),
    };

    await fetch('http://localhost:3000/emailcheck', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.match) {
          setErrorFor(email, "Email already exists");
          emailSuccess = false;
        }
        else {
          setSuccessFor(email);
          emailSuccess = true;
          alert('success');
        }

      });
  }
  return (firstnameSuccess && lastnameSuccess && emailSuccess && passwordSuccess && confirmPasswordSuccess)
}
```

https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/

Comment: It now alerts with ok all the time.